# Which spherical symmetric graphs are there?

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, markov-chains

I am interested which "relevant" infinite graphs G=(V,E) (or in my use cases called networks) are out there that are spherical symmetric,
i.e. for a fixed origin 0 and each pair $v,w \in V$ with the same distance n from the origin (=length of smallest possible path) there is an automorphism $\phi:V \to V$ on G that fixes the origin and $\phi(v) = w$.
So far I would say that d-regular trees fullfil this definition and a modified version of $Z^n$ where one adds, starting from the origin, straight lines in each direction in $Z^n$.

My motivation for this comes from the following theorem about the transience of such graphs.
Let $\partial V_n = \{v \in V: d(0,v)=n\}$ be all vertices with distance n from 0 and $E_n$ all edges between $V_n$ and $V_{n+1}$. Then a Markov chain on G is transient iff. $\sum_n \frac{1}{E_n} < \infty$.

Comment: There exists regular graphs with no non-trivial automorphisms (Frucht graph), why do you say d-regular graphs fulfill this definition ?

Comment: @caduk Oh, I'm sorry. This is my fault. In this context, I only considered infinite graphs as elsewhere a random walk on a finite graph would always be recurrent and the the whole theory cannot be applied or even considered. I will edit it right away

Comment: Even infinite $d$-regular graphs do not need to have any nontrivial automorphisms. and certainly do not need to be "spherical symmetric". (Also, I don't see the connection this question has to random graphs.)

Comment: I apologize. I had this topic coming up in a lecture about random graphs, so I added it without thinking to much about it but you're indeed right, the specific problem is not about random graphs. For the d-regular graph I just copied the term from my notes but now that you mentioned it, it seems we used the term carelessly as the lecturer was always talking about connected ones. So maybe d-regular trees is a more fitting word?

Comment: An infinite $d$-regular tree is indeed spherical symmetric. Even among connected $d$-regular graphs, though, it is an extremely special case. (I hope you don't mind that among the nitpicking, nobody is actually answering your question - but I'm not sure I know many good examples of infinite graphs like these, and have a hard time judging which are "relevant".)

Comment: @Misha Lavrov no problem, it was definitely me who ill posed the question. "Relevant" was also chosen for the lack of a suitable word that I don't know which one are interesting, highly investigated in different fields I don't know of because I'm more or less a beginner